# Power Query conditional formating color rows

Tags: powerquery, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to color the rows in a Power Query based on a formula?
I have tree conditional formats in my Excel sheet and would like them in a query
=$A2-TODAY()>13 (color green), =$A2-TODAY()<1 (color red), =$A2-TODDAY()<14 (color orange)

Comment: Cells inside the Query editor cannot be customized. The editor is just for data transformation.

Comment: You cannot add format like this in PowerQuery. But in PowerBI, you can. You should check the docs page for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting.